# Why can't bulk insert format csv?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I have this code:
`BULK INSERT [custdb].[dbo].[TB_T_DISP_PARTY] FROM 'd\DB\dbo.TB_T_DISP_PARTY.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FORMAT = 'CSV' );`

And then I get this error

'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near'FORMAT'.'

Can somebody tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: FORMAT only works on SQL 2017 and higher.  What version are you running?

Comment: I tried both SQL2017 and SQL 2018 but can't.

Answer (score 1):

[image: It just bcoz of Version Difference]

It is just bcoz of Version Difference

FORMAT = 'CSV' Applies to: SQL Server 2017 + Versions

Comment: I tried to copy the correct path, but still can't run.